# Programmatically create multiple views from custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I was able to create and combine multiple views from my custom view class which extends a LinearLayout, and it worked well. I followed this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978298/custom-view-made-of-multiple-views). But you have to create an XML file and inflate it to populate the custom view.

I want to do it **programmatically** not by using an XML layout and inflating it. Is this possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28473190/6727332 check this answer

Comment: Yeah, sure you can do that. You can instantiate `View`s with `new` just like any other regular Java class, and then use `addView()` to add them to your custom `ViewGroup` subclass.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer from my personal experience.

- You can use LayoutInflater to add multiple child view inside Parent view

Example :

- Parent View : FrameLayout
- Child View  : MyView

> LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
>
> View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.MyView, FrameLayout, false);
>
> FrameLayout.addView(view);

Answer (score 0):

to do so..

1. make your custom view that extends `View` class
2. make your custom viewgroup that extends `ViewGroup` class

and you can add your view in the viewgroup Using `addView()` method

view = https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View

viewgroup = https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup