# How to add a Layout from the resources to another Layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I want to display a LinearLayout from the XML-resources in another pre-existing one so I can easily make copies from the same model.

(without having to declare programmatically all the buttons, textViews...)

I'm looking for a method like the one that works for activities:

```
setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
```

Is it possible? And how?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can do this with create your layout and include in any other layout xml with using `include`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a layout file `sublayout.xml` and put this file in

```
YOUR_APP/app/src/main/res/layout
```

then you can include it by

```
<include layout="@layout/sublayout"/>
```

in another layout file.

Anyway, according to my experience, you can not
include `sublayout.xml` more than once, because
each id, like `android:id="@+id/sublayout_id1"` can only be used once.

Comment: Thanks! But I have another question ;) Is it possible to include the layout programmatically ?

Comment: Have a look here: [add Layout programmatically inside another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473145/add-layout-programmatically-inside-another-one)

Comment: Why do you need this. I never needed this. You can set the visibility of some layout to "gone" by `layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);` in the beginning, and when you need it, then `layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`. This has a similar effect like adding `layout1` programmatically. Anyway, it is simple, because you can just define `layout1` in the xml-file.

Comment: I need this because I add multiple elements from a database into the Activity. So I don't know how many of them I have to display before launching the activity... Anyway, the link you gave me seem to answer my question ;) Thank you for this! In fact I'm pretty new to Android, so I'm not yet used to the inflaters and so on...

Comment: Just in case, you are looking for a work-around (like I did it). I limited the maximum number of options (from server data) to 20. Then, you can do the "trick" with using visibility = gone (and if options > 20, then use button, to show next ... ).

Comment: Another work-around: Add all data to a String in a text field (in a scroll view) in separate lines and include a link for each option (instead of a button). This is a very quick solution (for prototyping or for production, if the formatting is nice). Some keywords: `SpannableStringBuilder` and `str1.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {@Override public void onClick(View widget) { some action } }, 0, str1.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);`

Comment: In fact I'm already adding all my layouts to a scrollView ;) At first I was only adding text as you say but, with all the lines I have, it became really ugly... Even if was trying (without succeeding at all) to format the lines... That is why using a single model of Layout repeted as much time as needed seemed better to me. But the idea of replacing buttons by links is nice! Thanks again!

Comment: OK. For the link in the `TextView tv` to work, you also need `tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`

Comment: Or use HTML for formatting just by: `tv_message.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.valueOf(ssb)));`
`tv_message.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`